# Windows Winsock redefinition errors regarding asio/SteamAPI/libssh/SDL_net

Tags: winapi, winsock, asio, libssh, sdl-net

Any time I try to use more than 1 networking library in the same (CMake) project, there are many Winsock redefinition errors. These libraries are `asio`, `SteamAPI`, `libssh`, and `SDL_net` to name a few.

[image: redefinition errors]

I turned to Google for answers, and there are many posts regarding this issue. Many people have proposed how to fix this such as defining `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` before including `Windows.h`, or not including `Windows.h` twice... I have removed all usages of `Windows.h`. I have also tried many variations of the answers in the hope of getting my program to compile. This makes no difference.

Among all of the available answers, there is not one single answer that solves this issue. Most of the answers do point to this being a WindowsAPI-only issue due to it trying to include the old `Winsock.h`.

Is there any way to use the networking libraries mentioned above simultaneously without these errors?

Answer (score 0):

`winsock.h` does not co-exist with `winsock2.h`. `winsock2.h` is designed to replace `winsock.h`, not extend it. As such, `winsock2.h` declares everything that `winsock.h` also declares.

If `winsock2.h` is included first then it disables `winsock.h` and all is well, but if `winsock.h` is included first then you get these kinds of redeclaration errors.

So, the solution is to make sure that `winsock2.h` is included before `winsock.h`.

For instance, by including `winsock2.h` before `windows.h` (which includes `winsock.h`) and all other socket libraries. You can also define `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` so `windows.h` doesn't include `winsock.h`.

Comment: I am not sure if my project has an issue in it, because even when I try to add WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN as a compile definition in the CMake, its the same issue (asio now complains that winsock.h was already included). It's hard for me to accept this answer when I keep running into the same issue. If my solution is the only one that works, I can only assume it might be for others, for now at least. Here is the CMakeLists.txt, including stuff I've commented when it failed https://github.com/PeriodicSeizures/Valhalla/blob/steam-server/CMakeLists.txt. I don't know what else to do at this point.

Comment: @crazicrafter1 you do not need to alter SDK headers to solve this problem.

Comment: @crazicrafter1 Try compiling without CMake. Once that works, translate that back to CMake.

Answer (score -3):

I believe I have discovered a solution to this problem. It involves modifying `Windows.h` located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\<version>\um`.

This works because all of the gunk that `Windows.h` includes is located within the `#ifndef` section for `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`, including `Winsock.h`.

Using a text editor, remove the `#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` section. It should be about 21 lines in length. Once removed, add `#include <Winsock2.h> to where the section was. Your computer might ask for permissions to save the file.

This worked for me, and I cannot assure it will work for you, but it very much should. Hope this helps.

Comment: Or, just define `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` in your code and then add `#include <WinSock2.h>`...

Comment: @crazicrafter1 - Arush Agarampur is correct. And hacking windows.h is definitely a Bad Idea.  Please consider DELETING this answer, and upvoting and "accepting" Remy Lebeau's answer instead.

Comment: Modifying *any* Windows SDK assets is not a solution to any problem. [Using the Windows Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/using-the-windows-headers) explains how to use the header files.